# How to specify the position of sub-menu div and prevent the menu div changed

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, submenu

I followed a tutorial about the dropdown menu from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp).

But I got stuck when I tried to implement the sub-menu. So far, I have managed to make this code.
HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown" style="float:left;">
  <button class="dropbtn">Left</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content" style="left:0;">
    <div class="dropdown-list draggable" href="#">Link 1
        <div class="dropdown-sub-list">
          <div class="draggable" href="#">Link 4</div>
          <div class="draggable" href="#">Link 5</div>
          <div class="draggable" href="#">Link 6</div>
          <div class="draggable" href="#">Link 7</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-list draggable" href="#">Link 2
    <div class="dropdown-sub-list">
          <div class="draggable" href="#">Link 4b</div>
          <div class="draggable" href="#">Link 5b</div>
          <div class="draggable" href="#">Link 6b</div>
          <div class="draggable" href="#">Link 7b</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-list draggable" href="#">Link 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-sub-list {
    display: none;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content .draggable {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content .draggable:hover{background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown-list:hover .dropdown-sub-list{
    display : block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/yusrilmaulidanraji/9sdck1z1/3/

The questions of mine are:

- How could I move the sub-menu to the exactly on the right side of the menu?
- How to prevent the resizing of the menu because of the appearance of the sub-menu?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you are ok with position then i think its what you want https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/9sdck1z1/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Pugazh/9sdck1z1/6/).

1. Add `position: relative`(so that the dropdown can be positioned to right) in `.dropdown-content .draggable`
2. Use `position: absolute` on `.dropdown-sub-list`. Also add `left: 100%`(moves drop down to the right); `top: 0` (moves drop down to the top)

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.dropdown-sub-list {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.dropdown-content .draggable {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown-content .draggable:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}
.dropdown-list:hover .dropdown-sub-list {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown" style="float:left;">
  <button class="dropbtn">Left</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content" style="left:0;">
    <div class="dropdown-list draggable" href="#">Link 1
      <div class="dropdown-sub-list">
        <div class="draggable" href="#">Link 4</div>
        <div class="draggable" href="#">Link 5</div>
        <div class="draggable" href="#">Link 6</div>
        <div class="draggable" href="#">Link 7</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-list draggable" href="#">Link 2
      <div class="dropdown-sub-list">
        <div class="draggable" href="#">Link 4b</div>
        <div class="draggable" href="#">Link 5b</div>
        <div class="draggable" href="#">Link 6b</div>
        <div class="draggable" href="#">Link 7b</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-list draggable" href="#">Link 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For your point number one, I tried to not put it on the css and it still works. Could you elaborate a bit about the drawback if I don't use it?

Comment: @YusrilMaulidanRaji - You are right, it will work because position relative is inherited from `.dropdown`. If not specified anywhere, the `dropdown-sub-list` may stick to the top of the browser.

Comment: Just try removing `position: relative` in `.dropdown` and `.dropdown-content .draggable`

Comment: Ok then thanks!
I have tried almost all the answer, but I like this one the most since there is `left: 100%;` so I don't need to specify the pixel. And also because it has an explanation + demo. Cheers!

Comment: Just one more question, I just realized that the top properties of sub-menu is not showed on the correct position (always on the top, not on the precisely right of the menu). Do you have a clue on how to fix it?

Comment: That's it! I just tried to remove the `top: 0` but it still had a glitch. But when I tried to keep it and add the `position: relative`. It works like a charm now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your css by this:

```
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {

    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-sub-list {
    display: none;

    float:right;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content .draggable {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content .draggable:hover{background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown-list:hover .dropdown-sub-list{
    display : block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute; "change here"
    right: 0;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-sub-list {
    display: none;
    top: 40px;
    position: absolute; "change here"
    float: left; "not sure you need this"
    right: -41px;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    z-index: 1; "change here"
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Done some changes in your css check fiddle link

https://jsfiddle.net/9sdck1z1/11/

```
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-sub-list {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    min-width: 160px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -160px;
    top: 0;

}

.dropdown-content .draggable {
   color: black;
    display: block;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown-content .draggable:hover{background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown-list.draggable:hover .dropdown-sub-list{

  display : block;
}


.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for CSS based dropdowns, they're a lot simpler ... that's a lot of 'pointless' DIVs.

I haven't styled it, but this is all you need to make it work.

(you don't need the class names .sub and .sub-2, but it will help you keep track of things when you style it)

HTML

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Left</a>
        <ul class="sub">
          <li><a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <ul class="sub-2">
              <li><a href="#">link 1 - 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">link 1 - 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">link 1 - 3</a></li>
            </ul> 
          </li>
          <li>link 2</li>
          <li>link 3</li>
        </ul> 
            </li>
</ul> 
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav li{list-style-type:none; }
nav ul.sub, nav ul.sub-2{display:none; }
nav ul li:hover .sub, nav .sub li:hover .sub-2{display:block; }
```